# For custom templates, is it better to use `template_include` or `type_template`?

Tags: customization, templates, page-template, template-hierarchy, template-include

I saw a lot of questions about including custom views in Wordpress (I mean custom templates).
There were many answers. Some people recommend using [template_include](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) and others recommend using [type_template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/)

My question is, which is better for working with custom templates? What are the pros and cons of both solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{type}_template` is a filter inside the [`get_query_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_template/) function. That function is called by a series of functions called `get_home_template`, `get_category_template` and so on. It allows you to very specifically target templates.

You can see it in action in [`template-loader.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php), where the `$tag_templates` variable is defined, binding conditions like `is_home`, `is_category` and so on to the functions. Depending on the condition the function is then executed on the line where it says `$template = call_user_func( $template_getter );`.

A bit further on in the file you see the `template_include` filter. This is the last possibility to change the template before it is actually loaded. This means anything you may have done with `{type}_template` can be overruled here.

So, if you have full control over your install, the semantically most correct way would be to use `{type}_template`, because that filter is meant to keep track of template changes under specific circumstances. It would keep your code more readable.

However, if you want to make sure plugins are not overruling your `{type}_template` filter, you would opt for `template_include`.